# Rewrite paths in script files during RPM installation?

Tags: sed, build, path, installation, rpm

I'm encountering the following problem:

In order to get my SPEC built into an RPM, I have to put the right path within my script files:

```
sed -i -- "s|/opt/my_app_folder|$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/my_app_folder|g" ./bin/startup.sh
```

If I don't, the %install part of the build fails because the script cannot find /opt/my_app_folder, indeed the build is done in $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/my_app_folder. However, I fear that this "sed" manner is a terrible manner to do it.

Moreover, when installing the built RPM, paths within script files are not rewritten, so I have to manually replace the /home/user001/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/my_app-1.0.0-0.x86_64/opt/my_app_folder with /opt/my_app_folder.

So I'm wondering what would be the proper manner:

- Should I use only relative paths in my files?
- Is there a SPEC option to have the files rewritten during RPM installation?
- Should I consider these files as conf files and rewrite them manually after installation?
- Or should I just not use the scripts during installation because it's not an RPM's purpose?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved 20 years ago; your scripts can use the GNU-standard [`DESTDIR`](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#DESTDIR). That *should* be unset during normal operation. The `%make_install` macro uses it properly.